# Searching in a balanced binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I was reading about balanced binary search tree. I found this statement about searching in such tree:

> It is not true that when you are looking for something in a balanced binary search tree with n elements, it can in worst case needed n/2 comparisons.

Why it is not true?

Isn't it that we look either to the right side or the left side of the tree so the comparisons should be n/2?

Comment: Because it is proportional to the height of the tree, not to the number of nodes it can contain ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following balanced binary tree for `n=7` (this is in fact a complete binary search tree, but lets leave that out of this discussion, as a complete binary search tree is also a balanced binary search tree).

```
          5                    depth 1 (root)
     /----+----\ 
    2           6              depth 2
 /--+--\     /--+--\ 
1       3   4       7          depth 3
```

For searching of any number in this tree, the worst case scenario is that we reach the maximum depth of the tree (e.g., 3 in this case), until we terminate the search. At depth 3, we have performed 3 comparisons, hence, at arbitrary depth `l`, we would have performed `l` comparisons.

Now, for a complete binary search tree as the one above, of arbitrary size, we can hold `1 + 2^(maxDepth-1)` different numbers. Now, let's say we have a complete binary search tree with exactly `n` (distinct) numbers. Then the following holds

```
n = 1 + 2^(maxDepth-1)  (+)
```

Hence

```
(+) <=> 2^(maxDepth-1) = n - 1 
    <=> log2(2^(maxDepth - 1)) = log2(n - 1)
    <=> maxDepth - 1 = log2(n - 1)

        => maxDepth = log2(n - 1) + 1
```

Recall from above that `maxDepth` told us the worst case number of comparisons for us to find a number (or it's non-existance) in our complete binary tree. Hence

```
worst case scenario, n nodes : log2(n-1) + 1
```

For studying asymptotic or *limiting* behaviour of this search, `n` can be considered *sufficiently large*, and hence `log2(n) ~= log2(n-1)` holds, and subsequently, we can say that a quite good (tight) upper bound for the algorithm is `O(log2(n))`. Hence

> The time complexity for searching in a complete binary tree, 
>   for `n` nodes, is `O(log2(n))`

For a non-complete binary search tree, an analogous reasoning as the one above leads to the same time complexity. Note that for a non-balanced search tree the worst case scenario for `n` nodes is `n` comparisons.

---

**Answer:** From above, it's clear that `O(n/2)` is not a proper bound for the time complexity of a binary search tree of size `n`; whereas however `O(log2(n))` is. (Note that the prior might be a *correct* bound for sufficiently large `n`, but not a very good/tight one!)

Comment: why in this table http://bigocheatsheet.com/ it does not say that time complexity of a binary search tree of size n is O(log2(n)) but it says it is O(log(n)) ... thanks

Comment: I quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Logarithmic_time: _"Due to the use of the binary numeral system by computers, the logarithm is frequently base 2 (that is, log2 n, sometimes written lg n)."_.  Since we're working with a _binary_ tree, the `2` is usually omitted (but to be inferred). Hence, in your cheat sheet, `O(log(n))` is the same as `O(log2(n))`.

Comment: @CarMar Happy to help. Remember to accept the answer which you think best answers the question, and possibly upvote all answers that you found helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: last question : is there any difference between searching in a BST and in Balanced Binary Search tree ?? ..thanks

Comment: Possibly a nit, and I know Wikipedia said it and not you, but I do not think it is correct to say the log is frequently base 2 because computers use binary. The complexity described in your answer has nothing to do with number base used by the computer implementation. It is a property of the divide and search strategy.

Comment: @The111 I agree that the wiki wording _"... use of the binary numeral"_ is ill-fated. Note however that nor is log2, _per se_, an inherent property of divide and search strategy; it's an inherent property of the (overwhelmingly) most common _binary_ divide and search/conquer strategy. E.g. when solving ILP:s in classic optimization by using branch-and-bound/cut (divide and conq.) techniques, the generated tree is not necessarily binary expansion w.r.t. tree depth. Perhaps a better wiki wording would have been along the lines _" ... frequent use of algorithms based on binary operations ... "_.

Comment: @CarMar As I wrote last paragraph before the _"Answer"_ clause, the worst-case scenario of a non-balanced BST in O(n). Consider the following example: http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/wp-content/blogs.dir/476/files/2012/04/i-8908e462401873fbddd042a25133f1fd-unbalanced-trees.jpg It's apparent that in the worst case scenario of a non-balanced case, the maximum tree depth equals the number of nodes in the tree, and to reach the node at the deepest depth, we'll need `n` comparison operations for a tree of `n` nodes. Hence, it's usually imperative that our BST:s are created to be somewhat balanced.

Answer (score 1):

The search worst case of `Balanced Binary Search tree` is governed by its height. It is **O(height)** where the height is `log2(n)` since it is balanced.

In worst case, the node that we looking for resides in a leaf or doesn't exist at all, and hence we need to traverse the tree from the root to its leafs which is **O(lgn)** and not **O(n/2)**

Comment: is not that the values in the right side of a binary search tree is bigger than the left side ? thanks

Comment: is there any difference between searching in a BST and in Balanced Binary Search tree ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the tree with 10 nodes: 1,2,3,4,5..10.
If you are looking for 5, how many comparisons would it take? How about if you look for 10?
It's actually never N/2.

Comment: why in this table http://bigocheatsheet.com/ it does not say that time complexity of a binary search tree of size n is O(log2(n)) but it says it is O(log(n)) ... thanks

Comment: It is the same thing. All logarithms the same thing in terms of big-O.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case scenario is that the element you are searching for is a leaf (or isn't contained in a tree), and the number of comparisons then is equal to tree height which is log2(n).

Answer (score 0):

The best balanced binary tree is the AVL tree. I say "the best" conditioned to the fact that their modifying operations are O(log(n)). If the tree is perfectly balanced, then its height is still less (but it is not known a way for modifying it in O(log(n)).

It could be shown that the maximum height of an AVL tree is less than

> 1.4404 log(n+2) - 0.3277

Consequently the worst case for a search in an AVL tree is an unsuccessful search whose path from the root ends in the deepest node. But by the previous result, this path cannot be longer than 1.4404 log(n+2) - 0.3277.

And since 1.4404 log(n+2) - 0.3277 < n/2, the statement is false (assuming a n enough large)

Answer (score 0):

lets first see the BST(binary search tree) properties which tell that..

```
-- root must be > then left_child 

-- root must be < right child


                  10
                 /  \
               8     12
              / \    /  \ 
             5  9   11   15
            / \          / \
           1   7        14  25
```

height of given tree is 3(number of edges in longest path 10-14).

suppose you query to search 14 in given balanced BST

```
          node--  10          14 > 10
                 /  \         go to right sub tree because all nodes  
               8     12       in right sub tree are > 10
              / \    /  \ 
             5  9   11   15    n = 11 total node
            / \          / \
           1   7        14  25  


        node--   12           14 > 12   
                /  \          again go to right sub tree..
              11   15
                   / \        n = 5   
                  14  25   


         node--  15       14 > 15 
                /  \      this time node value is > required value so 
               14  25       goto left sub tree
                           n = 3



             'node --  14       14 == 14 value find
                               n = 1'
```

from above example we can see that at every comparison size of problem(number of nodes) halve we can also say that at every comparison we switch to next level thus height of tree is increased by 1 .

as max height of balanced BST is log(N) in worst case we need to go to leaf of tree hence we take log(N) step to do so..

hence O of BST search is log(N).